# Is the multiplication modulo $p$ for polynomials well-defined?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> Is the multiplication modulo $p$ for polynomials well-defined ?

I mean let $g,h\in\mathbb Z[x]$ and let $\bar g$ be the polynomial obtained from $g$ by reducing all the coefficients of $g$ modulo $p$, the same for $h$. Is then $\overline{gh}=\bar g\cdot\bar h$ ? It should be actually but for example;

$g(x)=(p-1)x+1,\quad h(x)=x^2+x+1$ we have $g=\bar g, h=\bar h$

and $\bar g\cdot\bar h=(p-1)x^3+px^2+px+1$

but $\overline{g(x)h(x)}=\overline{\left((p-1)x+1\right)\left(x^2+x+1\right)}=(p-1)x^3+1$

Comment: These are equal in $\mathbb F_p[x]$.

Comment: @Engloutie so I have to consider the first result again $\mod p$, but then it holds for any integer $n$, or not ?

Comment: Even without introducing "polynomials", consider multiplying $3$ and $4$ modulo $7$.  While you might view $3$ and $4$ as already "reduced" mod $7$, taking the product $3\cdot 4 = 12$ gives a value in need of extra "reduction".  But $12 \equiv 5 \!\mod\! 7$, and the product is well-defined modulo a prime (or any modulus $n$ as you suggest).

Comment: To expand on Engloutie's comment, note than in the middle line we have
$$\bar{g} \cdot \bar{h} = \overline{(p - 1) x^3 + p x^2 + px + 1}$$ and that $$\overline{p x^2} = \bar{p} \bar{x}^2 = \bar{0} \bar{x}^2 = \bar{0},$$ and that the linear term is zero for the same reason.

Comment: @inequal Yes, the map $\mathbb Z[x] \to (\mathbb Z/n)[x],\ x \mapsto x$, is always a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @hardmath but It must not hold for any integer $n$, why is then there a theorem like ''mod p irreducibility test ?''

Comment: @inequal:  Sorry for any confusion, but I'm only saying that multiplication is *well-defined* modulo $n$, for polynomials as well as for the ring of integers.  Testing for irreducibility of a polynomial modulo $p$ (a prime modulus) can still enjoy a special case status without contradicting that multiplication modulo general $n$ is well-defined.

Comment: I recommend that you consider more closely the relationship between congruences, normal form reps (remainders), and cosets in quotient rings, etc. Your recent questions show that you are studying class groups of number fields, for which it is absolutely essential to have mastered such basic matters as above.